# WP - Show thumbnail of a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to include a specific page on the frontpage of a WordPress Theme.

The overal HTML structure should be similar to this:

```
<div>
     <h1>Om</h1>
     <p>Content comes here</p>
</div>

<div style="background-image: url(...)">
</div>
```

At the moment it echos the content of the page successfully.

Here is how that part works with PHP:

```
<div class="omtekst col-md-6 half-content-wrapper">
    <h1 class="semibold">Om</h1>
    <?php
        $my_id = 7;
        $post_id_7 = get_post($my_id);
        $content = $post_id_7->post_content;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
        echo $content;
    ?>
</div>
```

As mentioned earlier I want to include the thumbnail below this. This is where I am having problems.

However, I have started on the PHP to show how I am thinking. The thumbnail should be `$image` or similar.

```
<div class="ombilde col-md-6" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')">
```

Do you have a working solution for this?

**Edit**

My custom thumb which is not used with this image:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size' );
function mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size(){
    add_image_size( 'frontpage_thumb', 500 ); // Unlimited height
}
```

Enabled post thumbnails:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
    add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
    add_theme_support( 'widgets' );
}
```

Comment: From where you want to take a link to the image? From post with id = $my_id?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Yes, that was my thought, as both content and thumbnail are from the same post id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the url of image you can use

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id([ID_HERE]), [IMAGE SIZE HERE] );
```

then you can use

```
<div class="ombilde col-md-6" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
```

to get image size string look at your theme for "add_image_size" function

and as pgk said post-thumbnails have to be enabled inside functions but i guess you already did this

**edit:**

[ID_HERE] replace with post id

[IMAGE SIZE HERE] you can test this with "full"

Comment: Thank you, however, it only prints out `background-image: url('')`. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: This should work. Did you replace [...] with correct id and string, Did you notice the [0] after image? are you sure you have thumbnail on your page.

Comment: Tried it many times, and suddenly it works. Could be cache or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get post thumbnail, you can make this like that:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id_7->ID ) ) {
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id_7->ID, $size, $args );
}
```

This returns image tag. You can find more info here [Codex - get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)

Your theme must have  ‘post-thumbnail’ support enabled.

This is the easiast way to attach image to your post.

And if you are in theLoop, you can use `the_post_thumbnail()` function, it directly prints thumbnail image:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>
```

[Codex - the_post_thumbnail()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

If you want to print image as background, you must pit 'large' as $size.

Answer (score 1):

Use [wp_get_attachment_url($id)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) for retrieving the URL of the desired post.

In your example:

```
$my_id = 7;
            $post_id_7 = get_post($my_id);
            $my_thumb =  wp_get_attachment_url($my_id);
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $my_thumb; ?>')" class="omtekst col-md-6 half-content-wrapper">
        <h1 class="semibold">Om</h1>

    </div>
```